# Excluding wrong points in least square method

Tags: algorithms, least-squares

I am using least square method to find linear equation but getting some problems below. I would like to exclude wrong points before calculating linear line. Is there any idea for this?
[image]

Comment: Such algorithms are called [outlier detection methods](https://www.google.de/search?q=outlier+detection+methods).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the "wrong" points from the linear model before fitting it, you first need to define a criterion to decide which points are wrong. Otherwise, you can use several measures of influence such as Cook's distance or studentized residuals, but first you need to fit the entire model.

Comment: Thank you, AlexR and Augustin for the idea! Actually, I don't have a good definition now, just see it by eye.

Comment: It can be a good method as long as the dimension and size of sample are low.

Comment: Hi, did you mean Cook's distance method? In fact, the sample size is not so large only about 200 points.